# Como funciona o GroupBy no LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, operadores, group-by

Estou com dificuldades para entender o operador *GroupBy* no LINQ.

Comment: Você tem alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: não entendi a sintaxe

Comment: quero um exemplo

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/Bb534501(v=VS.100).aspx) serve para agrupar elementos de acordo com um determinado valor em comum entre eles. Por exemplo:

```
public class Fruta {
    public String Cor { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Suponha algo assim:

```
var frutas = new List<Fruta>();
```

Suponha também que colocamos várias frutas, com cores em comum, e queremos agrupar pelas cores:

```
var grupos = frutas.GroupBy(f => f.Cor);
```

`grupos` é um objeto que implementa [`IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Fruta>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb344977(v=vs.118).aspx). Ou seja, é uma lista de elementos de grupos.

Um objeto que implementa `IGrouping` basicamente tem dois elementos em sua estrutura:

- `Key`, ou seja, o valor chave do agrupamento (no nosso caso, o nome da fruta, uma `String`);
- `GetEnumerator`, ou seja, os elementos agrupados pelo valor chave. Aí aqui você pode usar o objeto diretamente, fazer um `ToList()`, usar outra extensão Linq, etc, etc, etc.

Repare que ele se parece muito com um dicionário.

Se quiser imprimir o nome dos grupos, posso fazer assim:

```
foreach (var nomeGrupo in grupos.Select(g => g.Key)) {
    Debug.WriteLine(nomeGrupo);
}
```

Se quiser imprimir as frutas de cada grupo, posso fazer assim:

```
foreach (var listaDeFrutasPorCor in grupos) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Imprimindo frutas da cor: " + listaDeFrutasPorCor.Key);
    Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------");
    foreach (var fruta in listaDeFrutasPorCor) {
        Debug.WriteLine(fruta.Nome);    
    }
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k8zh6x).

Comment: Perfeito Obrigado !

Answer (score 5):

Como o nome diz, ele agrupa dados baseado em algum critério. Ele funciona igual ou pelo menos de forma semelhante ao `GROUP BY` do SQL.

Com ele você gera um conjunto de dados baseado em outro conjunto que deve ter alguma "coluna" repetida. Você elimina a repetição deste dado.

Retirado da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        List<Pet> pets =
            new List<Pet>{ new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 },
                new Pet { Name="Daisy", Age=4 } };
        //está agrupando por idade e depois po nome.
        //Como existe dois pets com mesma idade eles serão agrupados
        var query = pets.GroupBy(pet => pet.Age, pet => pet.Name);
        foreach (var petGroup in query) {
            WriteLine(petGroup.Key);
            foreach (var name in petGroup) WriteLine("  {0}", name);
        }
    }
}
 
class Pet {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uj2SgP). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iuLXe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/GroupBy.cs).